# Where to ask about general things

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope

as it is off-topic for SO, to ask general question such as:

- What is the best technologies choice for such and such
- How to learn this and that.
- etc.

and I often came across the serious trouble like that, specifically, problems with selection the CORRECT technologies to use in my next projet.

So, I was wondering where I can ask for such questions if there is specific place

Comment: There are thousands of low-quality forums on the web that are happy to discuss anything.

Comment: Oh, sure, low-quality forums! I love how this briliant hint collected two upvotes and asker receives two downvotes probably from the same pros. Pathetic. I also feel in need for such site. Someone will fill this gap if stackoverflow cant/doesn't want.

Comment: @doc what do you want people to say?  Stack Exchange sites do not handle these types of questions.  There is no other answer.

Comment: @psubsee2003, I can see whet "doc" is coming from, there is NOTHING wrong with your answer and I've accepted it, many thanks, still having down votes for THIS question, I can't understand the reason how ever many times I think about it

Comment: @AbuRomaïssae I agree about the downvotes.  I never downvoted the question because I think it is a valid questions that others may have.    But the comment he was addressing is certainly a valid point.  But doc's assumptions are false.  The same 2 downvotes are not the 2 people who upvoted Woobles comment since i upvoted Woobles comment but did not downvote the question

Comment: @psubsee2003, well as the question is "valid" the problem face is real and serious, specially for the persons in charge, and certainly I wouldn't go as far as to name EVERY forum discussing them as "LOW-QUALITY"

Comment: the funny thing, is I guess I'll keep getting down votes from people not agreeing to this question, based on their opinion ^^

Comment: @psubsee2003 actually we all know Stack Exchange does not handle these types of questions and repeating this every time one mentions word "opinion" is really not necessary. Stack Exchange does not allow these kinds of questions, but this doesn't make StackExchange better/higher-quality; it's only different. And I don't force Woobie to comment so please dont ask me "what do you want people to say?".

Comment: @AbuRomaïssae I will try http://www.discourse.org/ and http://www.slant.co/. Seems that projects are just emerging.

Comment: You'll find *hundreds* of questions pertaining to generals on [history.se]...

Comment: Mind you, last time I looked in on slant they didn't seem to be going anywhere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking for something outside of Stack Exchange.  The types of questions you want to ask are better suited for forums and other sites the specialize in **Opinion** based answers.

No matter how you phrase it, questions of this type only invite someone's opinion as there is always multiple choices and none of the are going to be right and none will be wrong.

The Stack Exchange engine is designed around questions and answers, not topics and discussion, and questions of this type are always going to be discussions.

Your best bet is when you have a question of this nature, find an appropriate forum and ask there.

Comment: Does it really answer the question **where**?

Comment: It's not our job to be experts on things that aren't _here_. So 'somewhere else' is the best we're going to do for 'where'.

Comment: @bmargulies since when precise answers are not what SO is about?

Comment: @doc this isn't SO.  And you are just trolling.  If you feel you have something to offer this question, then step and add your own answer.

Comment: @psubsee2003 this is not stackoverflow? Then where am I. I've provided some tips in comment under question, but felt it is too few to post as an answer. If "somewhere else" is enough then O.K. I am a troll.

Comment: @doc: You on Meta Stackoverflow (not stackoverflow), where people are (i guess) experts on stackoverflow (as compared to experts on programming). at neither site are there experts on other websites, or on the web as a whole.

Comment: @doc While stackoverflow is about precise answers this question can't have a precise answer. Go to xy.com would not be precise. It would be your personal opinion that xy.com is the best place to discuss general programming questions. And opinions aren't precise at all. So yes "somewhere else" is the most precise answer that can be given on SO without being opinion afflicted.

Comment: @trixn I am much wiser now than few years ago, when this question was asked. TBH this discussion was a nonsense. Go to "xy.com" could be precise answer, if you have used objective measures to point to that specific website, couldn't it?

Comment: @doc What would be an objective measure for "xy.com is the best place to discuss general programming problems"? I agree that it could be precise if you provide them but afaik there are no such measures.