# Is it possible to ask general 'how to' questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

Is it possible to ask general 'how to' questions?

I think 'how to questions' are helpful for everyone. Yet I think they tend to get bad feedback in 2021.

In particular, is the moderating bot stepping in when it detects one?

Comment: Yes, though it's unfortunate that there's a group of... active users who routinely turn them into debugging questions and shut them down for not including debugging info.

Comment: Also note that while they are *allowed*, the same standards apply as all other questions. They should be clear, well-scoped, on-topic, etc.

Comment: "How to" can often be far too broad. Generic "How to" could easily be off topic for such reasons because the question ends up requiring an article length answer. "How to build Forum Software using PHP and MySQL" for example would be *way* off topic. There are, however, certainly times when it can be specific, but often those will be duplicates of existing questions. There's only, for example, so many times different people can ask "How to convert a string to an int in C#".

Comment: Replying to VLAZ, the term 'on-topic' confuses me. There is a way to interpret it as 'solely asking for debugging a specific reproducible problem' :(. What would be a better interpretation?

Comment: What do you mean "general"?

Comment: @Sam "*There is a way to interpret it as 'solely asking for debugging a specific reproducible problem'. What would be a better interpretation?*" [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [avoid asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). These cover most of it. On-topic are questions about developing software or writing code that are practical and answerable.

Comment: The devil is in the details. I'll illustrate that: You say *I think 'how to questions' are helpful for everyone*. I disagree with that broad version of the statement. I agree with *good how to questions are helpful for everyone*. And what makes a GOOD how-to question... that is a question all on it's own because boy do people manage to sabotage their intentions by filling them with landmines, red herrings and misdirection.

Comment: I usually end up down-voting them because they want any one of the million ways to skin a cat.  Usually it isn't even just the skinning part, they want a start-to-finish industrialized solution at scale.  Asking "how do I make my own Facebook" is too broad, I don't care how answerable you think it is.

Comment: I don't disagree, that "how to make facebook" is too broad. however, that's most certainly not the only or most common "how do i do x" question we get every day.

Comment: This site does not have a "moderating bot". All moderators are humans.

Comment: "Yet I think they tend to get bad feedback in 2021." Would like to get more statistics about that. Is that true? Anyway, it might be that people simply have not thought about the specific requirements of their problem enough. A general solution to a general question will likely not be very optimal in each case. And then suddenly people come back saying (yeah, but I need it faster and it know this) and then the question is why they hadn't said so right from the beginning.

Comment: @Cody Maybe OP's thinking of Community. Reviewers can add comments on behalf of Community, right? Plus, some questions might get automatically sent to review for low quality if they're especially short, right?

Comment: "All moderators are humans." @CodyGray bot has passed the Turing test.

Comment: Related meta questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357911/why-does-a-general-question-get-closed, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268305/what-is-an-indicator-that-a-question-is-too-broad-or-not, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314788/are-questions-asking-general-solutions-of-a-scenario-but-no-actual-codes-on-topi, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260577/where-to-ask-about-general-things

Comment: If your "how to" questions are as open-ended as this question, no.

Comment: It was, then it wasn't, then came the rise and fall of Documentation, and now it... is? I think.

Comment: @IanKemp I wanted to post this, but you beat me to it!

Comment: "How to" usually means "Code writing service"

Comment: Just like on main SO, some clear & concise examples would be helpful for a question like this

Comment: @mxmissile Nothing wrong with code writing in general. I know what you mean but how to questions are on general some of the most useful in SO. If in doubt I would always recommend to formulate a question as how to. That way it's at least clear that there will be a goal.

Comment: @camille If there were examples, people might discuss them instead of the desired general cases. As I understand it this question here wants to know where the line is between ontopic and offtopic too broad questions. There must be a limit somewhere. With a few examples you will hardly be able to define it. Better to find general guidelines. But hey, there is already a guideline that says that answers shouldn't be too long. That would require that the asker actually can estimate how big the scope will be of a question. This isn't really simple to do but with a bit of exercise ...

Comment: No, its impossible.

Comment: You can try but you'd be pressing your luck. They fall into a grey area. I would like to see more "How To" questions honestly, I don't really like debugging questions (as a reader, asker, or answerer).

Comment: @jrh Debugging questions are also how to questions with code already existing. Kind of how to fix this code. Problem with debugging questions is that people do often not provide a minimal example and they may be too specialized sometimes. The best questions for SO would be as general as possible without requiring answers that are several pages long. So I would bet my money on that there is an optimal size of the scope of an ideal question. But how do we guide people to effectively ask only these questions, I don't know.

Comment: @CodyGray: SmokeDetector is a bot, isn't it. And it is moderating. It is bringing posts to our attention in the Close Vote Chat.

Comment: @Trilarion It takes a significant amount of effort and judgement calls to moderate how to questions, but I think that's probably SO at its best, quick answers to quick questions. As a reader existing code isn't generally that useful because it's probably broken, as an answerer I probably wouldn't need it, as an asker there's no point in me asking anything anymore (I can debug my own code, thanks) and if I included everything I tried I'd overrun the character limit on the question and make it a mile long with (literally) irrelevant links and 15 dead end code implementations.

Comment: No, @ThomasWeller, SmokeDetector is not moderating. Moderators are a very specific thing on Stack Overflow. They have diamonds after their user names, and they are given an enhanced level of privileges. SmokeDetector has essentially no privileges on the site whatsoever, other than the ability to post in chat.

Comment: @CodyGray: ok, then I'm not moderating either? I thought the community is moderating. All of us. Some more (diamonds) some less (others)

Comment: You have actually earned many moderator-level privileges, @ThomasWeller, starting from the ability to vote, up through the ability to close, and even the ability to cast delete votes. Unless you're a bot, you still haven't proved that bots are involved in moderating the site. I'm harping on this because we all think that machines aren't sufficient to do the job; humans are needed, too.

Comment: @jrh Usually, when I encounter some exception I just copy the exception message to google, click on the first link to SO, scroll down to the first answer and try to apply whatever solution is printed there and surprisingly often it really works. Common problems have common solutions, even though technically it was probably a debugging question that asked for this. It all hinges on people having to isolate the problem first and then having to ask the right question. That is what everyone has to do by him/herself. The rest is done by SO. It's a nice division of work and makes SO so useful.

Comment: @CodyGray "...we all think that machines aren't sufficient to do the job..." Sure, but let's verify the truth of that statement from time to time again in the future. I'm not so sure it remains that way.

Comment: No, that sentiment is not going to change with the passage of time.

Answer (score 39):

That is the whole premise of the site. Stack Overflow is a repository of "How to ..." questions about programming. A reasonably scoped "how to" question is the most on-topic question there can be.

Some questions are also debugging questions, but they are rarely useful to a broader community. It's much more difficult to ask a good debugging question. They often get downvoted and closed (e.g. typo or duplicate).

If you meant questions about general computing, then no. Such questions are off-topic. It must be programming related as specified by the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The keyword here is **[reasonably scoped](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)**.  We also have a very explicit close reason for tutorial-type questions and those are definitely off-topic.  *"How to update multiple SQL rows at once?"* is a reasonably scoped question.  *"How to write an FPS game like Call of Duty?"* is not.  The former is a programming *problem*, the latter is an [entire *project*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318103/327083).

Comment: @J... The "explicit close reason" you're referring to is "Needs more focus", right?

Comment: @wjandrea I guess these days that's the one - more correct, I suppose, that we *used to* have an explicit close reason for "seeking tutorials".  I think that ended up lumped into "seeking books, libraries, etc".  If you're looking for a tutorial you're effectively looking for long-form didactic content (ie: a complete article, book, or tutorial series) and that's not what SO is meant for or optimized for.  In the past these types of questions would just accumulate links to off-site tutorials because such questions are just too broad to fully address in an answer here.

Comment: I've been here a long time (11½ years) and there's never been a close reason for "seeking tutorials". My standard response nowadays is to those question where no attempt was even made is  a comment saying "Stackoverflow is not a free coding service, nor is it intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation" and I vote to close them as needing more focus.

Comment: @martineau You perhaps didn't notice it, but we certainly did.  For years.  The exact text of the on-hold reason read:  *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*  It was only changed again just in the past couple of years.

Comment: Having made the bold claim _"A reasonably scoped "how to" question is **the most on-topic question there can be**"_ you really should provide some specific examples to back that up. I mean it sounds good, but is it _really true_?

Comment: @skomisa Do you mean like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-do-i-exit-the-vim-editor

Comment: @Dharman You're responding by asking my opinion, which is beside the point. Your short answer made an assertion that I thought would be more credible if some examples had been included to illustrate and support it. I'm not suggesting that you are right or wrong, but specific examples would provide clarity. That's all.

Comment: @J...: You're right, I forgot that the current "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more" explicitly mentioned tutorials at one point. Regardless, mapping a "How to …" question to that is too much of a stretch IMO. I think many folks nowadays use "Needs debugging details" to indicate to the OP that they're expected to a least make an attempt to it themselves (and include the code it in their question).

Answer (score 28):

Going to say that if we're speaking in broad strokes, the entirety of Stack Overflow is a "how-to" kind of site, but with the obvious caveat that it's not often *verbatim* "How to do X"-style questions that get accepted or lauded or at least not moderated.

There are two very different kinds of how-to questions:

- How do I accomplish X, having tried Y?  ([Or its variant](https://xyproblem.info/), needing to solve X, trying Y, but getting stuck with Y, and asking about Y instead of X)
- How do I accomplish X?

The first one is generally the kind of Q&A that is acceptable.  You need to solve a problem and you have shown some of your work or research, and not just declared it (e.g. "I searched for ages", "I looked at everything", "I can't find it anywhere", etc).  This is often times the best way to go about asking a question, since it means that there's a clear scope and an answer exists that can generally be agreed upon as "correct".

The second one is generally the kind of Q&A that *isn't* acceptable, but there can be exceptions.  These come across as [the typical requirements dump](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353940/1079354) of someone who says, "I just don't know where to start".  What they don't realize is that this makes the both of us.  Even worse, this is where someone decides to state their knowns and the outcome they want without *any* indication that they've got something to work with as a baseline.

So, what can you take away from all of this?

If you want to ask "how-to", then you should be cool with showing your work on what you've attempted.  If you want us to answer the generic how-to, that will absolutely encourage the human curators (there aren't many bots that directly perform moderation tasks out there btw) to show up to curate your question.

Comment: I've also been flagged for asking questions that were deemed 'opinion' questions. It was a technical question, but I asked it in terms of 'is there a better way to do this', which got immediately moderated and shut down. You can tell I'm still b***hurt about it, but I'm still looking for the right forum to put such questions.

Comment: @CurtEckhart:  It's because "is there a better way to do this" is such an open-ended question that there can't be any one answer to it.  This is the point I make when I say that an answer exists that can generally be agreed upon as "correct"; there's a lot of "better" ways to do something, but unless there was explicit and specific criteria as to what "better" was, there would be no way to say that any of them were "correct".

Comment: @Alexi. I appreciate your advice. I respectfully withdraw my comment.

Comment: @CurtEckhart the fact you refer to "a forum" tells me right away you don't understand the long term goals of SO. If you treat it like a forum you will be disappointed.

Comment: @Makoto is what you write a rule, or wishful thinking? Can you provide sources for curators curating "generic how-to" questions? You may want to take a look at the Git tag, for example.

Comment: @Makoto - do you have thoughts about *why* type 2 isn't acceptable?  I'm curious if you think it provides net benefit to the site content. (I'm not so sure it does).

Comment: @CodeCaster:  It's the convention I've observed over the years.  If the Git tag is suffering from the same affliction, start another Meta question about this to see if something *could* be done.  In moderating tool questions, it's could be seen as *sorta* tough to not have only "how do I do X"-style questions, but what I'm really referring to are more the questions that just ask "how do I do X" with literally no research whatsoever, with the expectation that we teach them as opposed to helping them.

Comment: @danh:  Type 2 in coding questions can result in someone basically getting free labor or someone to write their code for them.  While I'm not generally opposed to that in philosophy, that's *not* the role that Stack Overflow set out for itself.

Answer (score 17):

It's possible to ask general how-to questions, but there are some challenges.

First and foremost, (probably more important than any of the rest of this answer) it's much more difficult to ask how-to questions now than it used to be because so many of them have already been asked and answered, especially the most simple and straightforward ones. The first part of asking a question here should be searching the site to see if it already exists. There's a good chance it does, but I've realized that searching is a skill not to be taken for granted.

If you have already searched and you're feeling certain that your question isn't a duplicate, the next challenge is accurately communicating what you're trying to do. It's hard to see the question as other people will see it. It may seem perfectly clear to you, but you already have all the necessary background information in your head, and it can be difficult to know which of that information is necessary to include. In general, it's best to assume as little as possible about what other people know when you're writing the question, and plan on sticking around for a while after you post it to respond to any requests for clarification people may have.

Then there's the tricky part. Not everyone here has the same standards about what makes a good how-to question, so you'll get mixed results depending on who sees the question, based on how "general" you've made it. The type of disagreement you see in the comments under your question is not unusual. Most people do seem to agree that part of the expected research effort when asking a question is to *try something*, regardless of whether or not they agree that it's necessary to include that in the question. That's not an unreasonable expectation, in my opinion. The work you put into it will help you ask a better question, it will help you understand the answers given, and if you have done it, then there's probably some sort of code you *could* include in the question.

Is a code sample necessary in a how-to question? In theory, I personally think the answer is something like maybe, often, probably, but it depends. That's just my opinion, and I know others see it as more of a clear yes/no. The person asking the question may not be the best judge of whether or not it's necessary, but ultimately they have to use their own judgement. Pragmatically, though, if you ask a question with no code in it, it's much more likely to get downvoted and closed, whether that's right or fair or not. I'm not suggesting that people should disguise their how-to questions as debugging questions, but including an example of your attempt to figure it out yourself will satisfy people who think that some code is required, and those who don't won't be bothered that it's there, but really it's more likely than not to at least help clarify what it is you're trying to do even though it doesn't work.

People seem reluctant to show their work. I often get the impression that because whatever they tried didn't work, people are afraid they're going to look stupid, and they want to avoid that embarrassment. That's understandable, but it's counterproductive. If you already knew how to do the thing, you wouldn't be trying to ask the question, so it's expected that whatever you tried will show some lack of understanding. It's best to just accept that from the beginning.

Comment: "People seem reluctant to show their work." Not because of the reasons you've listed, but because they haven't done any and expect us to do everything for them.

Comment: Sure, there are people like that too. I doubt they're going to be reading any of this, though.

Comment: @IanKemp "...expect us to do everything for them..." Which we probably even do if the question was at least half interesting and not a duplicate. The show your research requirement is not to avoid too simple questions but to avoid asking the same simple questions over and over again (in slightly different words).

Answer (score 7):

"How to" questions are fine, as long as they're unique and specific.

Stack Overflow is not your project plan generator. If you have to import some data from some external CRM into your organization's database and then ping the inhouse system that you've done so, this is the wrong way of going about that:

> #### How to import external CRM data to our internal systems?
>
> Please mention all the details.

This means that you've run to Stack Overflow about five steps too early. When solving a problem (and choosing to solve that problem by creating more problems, namely to program it yourself), you need to break that problem up into manageable pieces. So first, it's requirements gathering time. Then you don't know what you don't know, so it's research time. Ultimately, the following very valid questions could arise:

- How to authenticate my custom app against [Big Box CRM system] with OAuth? - Chances are there's documentation, an API, example code, so you probably don't need to ask this question. If you do, it's about OAuth and not your internal systems.
- How to synchronize customer data that was updated in two systems? - That's a business requirement. You'll need to ask yourself, the product owner or anyone else with a say in it what you want to do. Take the latest modifications? Merge the records somehow?
- How to let my HTTP client call the outside world? I get a proxy error - Go talk to your network administrators.
- How to create an always-running daemon on Windows? - That's called a Windows Service, go search.
- How to notify our homegrown CRM that I put something in its database which it should recalculate? - We don't know, ask the original developer or give enough details so we can have a go at it.

And so on. Some "How To" questions are on-topic, if they're narrowly scoped, well-defined and thereby ask a very answerable question.

The point I'm making here is that for example *"How to call an HTTP REST API from C#?"* is a very valid question. You don't need to show several lines of non-working, unrelated code that you found on a blog from 2001 and still uses HttpWebRequest and throw your compiler errors at us. Nobody is interested in getting that old garbage to work, you want to know how to do it in 2021. The answer is simply "Use an HttpClient". If your next question is *"And how do I send a JSON object with my request?"*, then that's a new question. Both questions have been asked and answered plenty of times before.

They're fine questions, just not to ask again, because you can search for them and find the answer yourself. Asking a duplicate question is not a deadly sin, because By $Deity, there are hundreds of similar questions per subject and some or most of them are outdated, or simply unfindable because even Google gives up and starts returning old blogs again. Just don't get angry if someone finds a duplicate and closes your question.

If the question comes down to "break down this huge problem into smaller steps for me", then you need to ask a more senior developer, a business consultant or a freelancer. Those are not questions that Stack Overflow can answer for you.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to ask general 'how to' questions?

Yes, unless they become too broad, i.e. good answers would fill many pages or even books. Indeed I imagine that good answers quickly can become really large if the question's scope gets larger and larger.

And that points to why general questions aren't a good fit for SO in general. Very often, the practical problem you may face is not general, but special in some way and there are specific requirements. The optimal solution will depend on these requirements (for example possible choices of programming languages, a certain kind of input data or deployment systems,...)  and good solutions will make use of these specific circumstances. Dividing general problems into answerable more specific (and practically relevant) problems greatly enhances the usefulness of the content.

If you ask general questions, you might just get general answers here, which might be much less useful than anticipated, even if the idea behind asking them is educational (i.e. wanting to learn the field). I think that text books or tutorials are a better fit for this, but I could also imagine some kind of meta questions (but still ontopic), where you basically ask about a very general topic and people answer with related Q&A pairs. Or [Articles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/articles) could be something for general questions but they aren't there yet.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: It depends.

Whether or not it is OK is based on if your question is clear and focused.

Let's look at Exhibit A: [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch/1783426)

The question is:

- Clear - it's very clear what the OP wants, in this case, checking out a remote Git branch.
- Focused - it's only asking one thing. This is what people mean when they say "Stack Overflow is not a code writing service." We will not write a whole program for you. However, SO is, at the same time, a code writing service for those who are very focused and clear.

Now let's look at Exhibit B:
[image: bad question]
(The timestamp on my computer says July 19, so it's about 4 months old now.)

- It's not clear. There's no sample input and output.
- It's definitely not focused. There are multiple things to do in this problem, and the OP **wants us to solve all of them**.

> I think 'how to questions' are helpful for everyone. Yet I think they tend to get bad feedback in 2021.

Yes, they *are* helpful for everyone if they are detailed and focused. The image above will not be useful to future readers. Who would have the *exact same problem*?

One possible reason why they get bad feedback now is that **pretty much all the simple how-to questions already have been asked.** So they get closed as duplicate, or if they are unfocused, "needs more focus".

If you share a specific piece of code that triggers a NullPointerException, and you include all the details, the question is clear and focused. But… it’s already been asked thousands of times.

Another way of determining if a how-to question is appropriate is to look for a close reason that describes the question. If it doesn't meet the criteria for any close reason and is not spam/offensive, then it should be okay.

So: ***It depends***!

Answer (score -11):

No

Questions which ask for opinion or questions which can have many possible answers are closed. “How to” questions fall into this category. Questions which don’t get closed on Stack Overflow are questions which can have a single correct answer.

It is a pity that Stack Overflow is closed to questions which require more general answers or opinions. Allowing experts provide advice in open forum would be very valuable. Stack Overflow encourages people to answer questions more that it must encourage to ask questions. The ratio of consumers to contributors means that this must be the case. The result is that the site favors questions which are faster to answer and easier to verify as correct.

Comment: I was a long-time contributor to this site, and I quit because I didn’t like how people looking for help here were treated. I recently came back to see if things have changed and to try to help some people.

Comment: And you think discouraging people from asking in-scope “how to” questions will help people? Color me confused.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The way the site is moderated right now there is effectively no such thing as an in-scope “how to” question. I wish they were allowed.

Comment: And yet, they are [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70047481/215552), [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70047349/215552), and [upvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70047078/215552) quite often (those just in the last day).

Comment: @HereticMonkey A few slipped through :)

Comment: [I think there's more than a few](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a1..%20answers%3a1..%20%22How%20to%22)... (2,298,347 results when I last ran it)

Comment: @HereticMonkey A “how to” question is a question which askes how to do something, not a question which has “how to” in the title. If someone asks how to do something on Stack Overflow it will be closed. It’s not useful to debate if this happens. It just might be useful to debate if this must happen.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The last one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70047078/how-to-re-start-the-julia-kernel-in-vs-code is basically tech support. Doesn't count,

Comment: @ShambhavGautam Well, that's one down, 2,298,346 to go... And that's undercounting. As HappyMoose mentions, it's not just that it has "how to" in the title; it could be phrased "how could I", "how can", "is it possible to", "what's the best way to", etc.. There are at least hundreds of thousands, if not millions of questions on Stack Overflow that meet the criteria. Are new ones often closed? Sure, because they're often duplicates. The pity is that many people are unwilling to put in the time to research to find the duplicates or apply the logic necessary to use the dupe on their own question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I never argued of asked any of this. Tech support how to is not the same as programming how to. That's just all I mean.

Answer (score -14):

I'm going to be blatantly honest and give a yes or no answer.

No.

It'll get closed because of the so called "Lack of debugging info" because they're like "Oh my god, it's an XY question! Unacceptable!". [XY questions](https://xyproblem.info/) may be bad, but that doesn't mean they're off-topic. In some cases, asking the X instead of the Y might be less well received. After all, your Y could be someone's X, so they're far from off-topic, if you ask an XY question, it's going to harm you; not the site. So, XY questions should be okay. In fact, XY questions should be asked. Even if you now know how to solve the problem, you need to know why the other solutions you tried had failed. You should ask both an X and a Y question.

People will somehow find a way to see your "How to" as an XY and close it because it somehow lacks debugging information. To be honest, Stack Overflow is just a competition for whose bug is the hardest to solve these days.

There aren't really any straightforward "How to" questions left after so many years and if you're going to ask one, it is going to be specific and will probably be seen as an XY due to that.

I will get downvotes for saying this and due to the meta effect, my reputation will get lower, but I'm unafraid of saying the truth. All useful Stack Overflow stuff are a few years old, these days, it's just debugging people's problems. And maybe someone has an interesting problem, in which case it may be useful.

So, treat Stack Overflow like an archived website and a debugging help website. Other than that, you're off to a fall. There are many people, and you will get your answer at least as a comment, but you'll soon get banned from asking questions.

There aren't really any new questions to be asked these days, other than debugging ones, so it is expected. We'll have to wait for a new language to blow up.

<sub>Okay, now you may downvote this (or upvote). Just do whatever you like, but please don't go downvoting my Stack Overflow questions and answers just because you hate me.</sub>

Comment: I'm really wondering who "they" are. I usually consider myself one of "them" when it comes to downvoting and closing, yet there are 4 "How to ..." questions on the first page of my answered questions.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The fact that you answer how to questions feels irrelevant. No one has put personal blame on you.

Comment: That's why I'm wondering who "they" are. Apparently, *someone* is to blame.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi What do you expect me to do? Give a highly subjective list of names?

Comment: If someone does go downvoting your Stack Overflow posts just because they hate you, there's an automatic script that will reverse those downvotes. I think you may have an overly broad definition of the "meta effect"; typically that's reserved for adding a link to a specific SO post to a Meta post, and seeing an increase in voting activity, not a link to a person.

Comment: It seems you had a rather extreme experience, and at least for me it is impossible to relate to it in such broad terms. I do not recommend shaming individuals, but if you do see such an extreme misbehaviour as the answer implies then some concrete information – be it statistics from SEDE or an honest sample of the questions you come across – may be useful.

Comment: @HereticMonkey There's no such word for that happening for an individual. "Meta effect" is the best word that exists that one can understand. I know, such downvotes will be reversed but if only a few people do it and only for a few posts, the system can't do anything.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm not blaming anyone, I'm just telling the truth and I think it's the case because there's no new library or a language which is blowing up right now. People just find absurd reasons to close questions due to that. Although I did have an especially bad experience with it and got my question closed just because I informed it was an XY or else the question would've been fine.

Comment: *"There aren't really any new questions to be asked these days"*: I disagree. There is a lot moving, with a lots of new technologies, frameworks, languages, and features. Always room for really new (not duplicate) questions.

Comment: @trincot Can you give a few examples?

Comment: Your top tag seems to be Python, which is pretty hot on ``async``, ``typing`` and now pattern matching for just the batteries included. There are tons of third-party libraries around it which do not rest either. That's a decades old language, and it's far from "done".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi My top tag may be Python, but that's due to people being interested more in Python. I'm by far a C and Go guy. If you're replying to the question I asked to trincot, I asked for examples, not tags. Well, Python is of it's own kind tbh. It's a scripting language which is used for stuff more than scripting. It's the only language used for everything(except making OSes), not that it's good to do so, but it's done. It's obviously going to have new hot things.

Comment: Not sure why there's any argument here.  Shambhav Gautam spoke the truth, and he predicted he'd get downvoted for it, and he did.  It's the kind of truth you're not allowed to tell.  (I suppose he might not have gotten downvoted so badly if he hadn't spoken so flamboyantly.)

Comment: My experience on the C tag is that with rare exceptions you *must* show code.  If you ask how to do something, people insist on seeing what you tried — which you can't do, because you can't write the code, because you don't know how.  You will be told — perhaps correctly — that asking questions on SO is not a substitute for learning the language or reading a manual.

Comment: @SteveSummit In C, there are many many, mostly low level how tos that aren't really asking about the language specification. People show the same reaction to them even if they could give a proper SO answer just because it's an XY. My point of emphasis is that people hate XY questions even though they maybe answerable and might help future visitors. And there's no argument here, people are just trying to dig out some obscure sideline point and prove it wrong and no one's disagreeing with the main point being "People hate XY and think specific how tos are XYs".

Comment: @SteveSummit Yep, if I said the same thing in an SO positive way, this answer would've gotten upvotes. The other answers are saying the same thing, except they're saying "Yes, but with exceptions" and I'm saying "No, with a few exceptions", and I think the later is more accurate.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The other answers say “Yes, but”. In reality, there is always a “but”.

Comment: I think this is a more realistic picture of SO, even an expert programmer would have a hard time coming up with a "How To" question (especially one without code) that would survive more than a few hours (even though I think they can be informative if done right).

Comment: Re *"We'll have to wait for a new language to blow up*: Well, [new JavaScript libraries are introduced every week](https://hackernoon.com/how-it-feels-to-learn-javascript-in-2016-d3a717dd577f) (even Wikipedia can no longer keep up), and sometimes [Microsoft screws up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979522/) (e.g., the update of [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) to version 1.62.2) and ruins everybody's workflow.

Comment: It also depends on the tag. There is an endless stream of questions about moving data around in [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29) tables. They are seldomly closed.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Don't even talk about Pandas. Every day, we get crazy specific questions like "How to merge data frames with the same first value and make shrink it after 7 seconds and make the last cell fall" and they don't get closed.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Libraries might be getting introduced but there's none which is getting super trendy and on a journey to replacing the old one as far as I know. And wait, I am using 1.62.2. Nothing happened. Well, I'll not wait for anything else to happen and update to 1.62.3 now.