# Should this question have been closed as "seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries and more"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70073221/save-crash-logs-in-file-javascript) was closed as "seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries and more", but I don't see it... The question simply asks if there is a way to save crash logs in a file. Not for a library that helps with it. I still think it should be closed though, as "needs details or clarity". The close reason should have been better chosen, as things like this can make newer users confused.

My guess on why it was closed for that reason was this comment:

> Have you thought about using something like sentry?

The main question however had no part asking for libraries.

Comment: The question seems low-quality. But certainly, it was not "seeking recommendations".

Comment: I don't think it's worth bringing this up here. (Low-quality) Questions get closed with the wrong reason all the time. You can vote to reopen, leave a comment to help OP improve the question or flag if you think some of the close voters are acting maliciously.

Comment: The question is so vague & general, how is it *not* asking for libraries & more?

Comment: Unfortunately anyone who asks a question and hints that rather than writing the code by hand, they would be prepared to reuse existing code if available, runs the risk of having the question closed with this closure reason. It's a crazy policy: we should be encouraging reuse of library code rather than discouraging it.

Comment: If there isn't a valid close reason to close the question, it shouldn't be closed. The close reason  provides valuable feedback to the OP.  Closing questions using random reasons  for whatever holy reason should be shunned. The end doesn't justify the means.

Comment: This is not some unique incident. Close reason are wrong in so many cases. The default reasons that can be selected are in many cases overlapping and in other cases there is no default reason that fits. It's a well known problem but nothing is done to solve it. As SO user all we can do is  to accept that close reason doesn't really have much meaning.

Comment: @4386427 "Close reason are wrong in so many cases." That's also the fault of the company partly. Their software only displays a single close reason, even if the reviewers did not agree on that. On the other hand: errare humanum est.

Comment: @TheMaster Sometimes close votes are not exactly accurate. However, just because they are not accurate, does not mean question should be reopened. This one was obvious duplicate. If it is not closed as duplicate all that is needed is leaving the comment with link to duplicate.

Comment: It feels like someone messed up the reason. I guess a mod made a mistake and closed it with the wrong reason.

Comment: @ShambhavGautam last I saw, it was a vote. Whichever one has the most votes gets chosen as the reason - but I don't know what happens if all 3 mods choose different reasons

Comment: @MrMythical Maybe somewhere in the way to the question being closed, something messed up. It's blatantly clear that this is not seeking for book recommendations. Might be that people just followed the first guy, being social creatures, or something like that. Crazy things happen. This is surely not a controversial topic, probably human weirdness or a system bug.

Comment: I would guess the first reason would be chosen if all 3 close-voters choose different reasons - since usually the first finished is a tie-breaker

Comment: @ShambhavGautam, mods don't "vote to close", one mod can immediately close it.

Comment: Its just as surprising that after getting reopened and closed again it was reopened *again*

Comment: @PCM I'm not talking about mods, I'm talking about other people. I was talking about mods in the last one.

Comment: Maybe call mods mods and users users

Comment: @KevinB it's confusing because closing the question is a user moderating the site. That's why instead of "mods" and "users" for close votes, I just say "close-voters"

Comment: Yes, but calling users mods suggests these users are somehow special, they're not, they're users, by calling them users, we reinforce that the job of keeping this site useful is everyone's, not just the people who got elected.

Comment: If a question is closed on the site, and we believe it should be closed, what is the problem?

Comment: @Braiam the issue is that it was closed for the wrong reason. The (unrelated) feedback could confuse the OP

Comment: @VLAZ [Who's On First?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who%27s_on_First%3F)

Comment: Are you aware that the message that you are shown is not the one that OP reads? All messages says "ask a new question" as their actionable course of action. So, it matters not what you close it, since if OP follows the instructions to the T, it would ask the same question again. It's more important to close it than bother with the minutae of what reason to use.

Comment: yeah, no, it's more important close questions properly so that we can get the tools/wording fixed to adequately inform the user how to proceed. That the system provides poor guidance today isn't an excuse to be lazy and use any old reason. Feel free to just not close questions, if you can't be bothered to choose the correct reason.

Comment: Or if you can't find a close reason that's a good match *Don't vote to close.* Downvote if the question's bad and move on. Drop a comment explaining the downvote if it seems fitting and hasn't already been covered by another comment.

Comment: @Hills A bit late, but to me, what you detailed seems like the normal process of improving a bad question. There's a difference between "there's no bad questions" and "just because a question is bad, doesn't mean it needs to remain bad for all eternity".

Comment: 1/2 - That is not a bad question, does not ask for code, and the comment about sentry would be a good enough answer. It was surely not very specific, but you can always collaborate with the OP (if he's willing to) to improve it. I don't even agree with the current closing reason, he's talking about a discord bot, the other is just asking how to write logs to file, they may look similar, but the answer may vary a lot (never wrote anything for discord so i'm not sure, but if i did i would probably look for something like this question and not the one it allegedly duplicates).

Comment: 2/2 - SO purists want no code asked, but think that the only answer can be code. I saw many questions closed with the excuse of "wE wOn'T dO yOu hOmEwOrK" just because it provided no code, was a "how can i..." question, or both. Even if SO is about programming it doesn't mean that everything has to orbit around code: "You can do A, then B or you can try C" is the right answer for this kinds of codeless questions and works just fine, even if you don't write a single line of code. Many people just need to be redirected on the right path, not everything on SO has to be about bugs resolution...

Comment: @FabioR. The last example I have is one question about security. A good question (now we have a different exchange for that), but as I have seen before also it got closed mainly becaue "you don't handle your own security, you let someone else do that". And I wonder, where did that somebody else start out. There are too many people on this site that are not here mainly to provide answers, but to "play" for "achievements", like it's their game. On top of that you can add what happens when you give some people just a slight hint of power.

Comment: Well, that was quick, [Is it possible to ask general 'how to' questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413152) -- I'm OK with closing it as a dupe/downvoted for lack of research (which it is now), but closing it as a book recommendation question seems to agree more with the [most downvoted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/413181) on the meta topic I linked than the [most upvoted one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/413153). Would be nice to have some consistency here. Not everyone wants or needs to use a third party logging library, I don't.

Comment: Maybe we should stop calling them bad questions and start calling by their official name: Not Useful. Note that just because it's not useful doesn't mean it should be closed. And that said, a huge portion of "Do My Homework" questions need focus because they're asking about the whole assignment, something usually made up of multiple steps.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The SO question in... question has now been closed as a dupe, so this Meta question as stated is no longer applicable. However, since this *topic* ("should questions be allowed to be closed for any arbitrary reason?" is important, I've answered it below.

---

No, it technically shouldn't have been closed with that reason. But realistically, **close reasons don't actually matter**.

That's because most of them used to be quite specific and helpful, but over the years many have been so diluted and made so ambiguous as to effectively be useless at providing **actionable** feedback to askers... which is ostensibly the entire rationale for these reasons to exist.

As a result, many curators are no longer as careful with selecting a close reason as they once were. There's also ever-increasing volumes of bad questions, and if you have to choose between agonising between the "most correct" close reason or closing 10 more bad questions in a day, most curators are going to pick the latter. Then there's the fact that evermore of the bad questions that do get closed are never revisited by their one-shot-wonder askers; if a close reason is provided but never read, it doesn't matter *what* reason was provided.

Yes, you should always try to be as accurate as possible when choosing to close a question. But reality doesn't work that way - when workloads increase, people start to take shortcuts, and that's what's happening with bad questions and their curators.

Comment: I think that before closing a question people should ask themselves if the question can be improved and if it can still help someone. Blindly closing every "not so great" question because "oh, if i was wrong they can still get revisited" is not the smartest way to proceed, many people won't even try to improve it, stick with that and look for a solution somewhere else when maybe that solution might have been helpful on SO

Comment: Why spend so much time on closing or downvoting when this time and energy could go into actually answering or improving the question itself. One does not need to be a moderator to do that. It's not really your responsibility (or only a few moderators) to decide whether or not a question is good or bad and that is a big flaw in the logic of this site.

Comment: I still stand by my motto: there are never bad questions, only bad answers. It's time to think about it, because in the end you will only be left with those type of questions - everyone else will be gone and so will the time many of you have spent using this site as some kind of personal CV (please use Github for that).

Comment: @Hills this isn't necessarily matter of responsibility. For  folks like me for example curating inappropriate questions is a matter of [keeping site worthy for us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367319/839601), "I want Stack Overflow to keep helping people like me - those who get their answers here after dumping their question into google search box... I don't want my search results polluted with useless solutions to homework dumps. I don't want it to be flooded with thousand answers to single simple question about NPE / NRE..."

Comment: @Hills Put things in perspective. Stack Overflow receives [12 million visits a day](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic), which is several magnitudes more than the six thousand questions asked a day. With that strategy, we'd be inefficiently helping a bit more than 6 thousand people while leaving the repository in a mess. With curation, we're helping site visitors, a much larger slice of the developer population.

Comment: @Hills In fact, it is not the job of moderators to improve questions at all. We deal only with content or users that are causing problems. Exactly as you said, anyone can and should try to improve posts whenever possible. That is always preferred over closing. Unfortunately, in most cases, it is simply not possible for a third party to improve a question to the point where it meets Stack Overflow's strict standards, and that leaves third parties with little choice other than to close it. Note that closure doesn't mean a question is "bad", only that it's unsuitable *for this site*.

Comment: While I sympathize with the frustration here, and I certainly understand that when operating on a scale like SO does, mistakes will inevitably be made (and will appear to be made far more often than they actually are), I do have some concerns about the apparent disclaimer of personal responsibility that certain portions of this answer implies. Every vote you cast, for the reason you cast it, is something you are personally responsible for standing behind, including its applicability to the post on which you cast it. If you can't stake that claim or suffer that responsibility, don't vote.

Comment: @gnat you always have to remember that as a highly specific, well made and very complicated question might be the best for your current level of expertise, an easy, short and "noobie" questions might be helpful to someone else. For example even a "What is an Array" question (provided that has not been already asked) might be helpful to someone that has just got into this world and, since SO shows you only what you are looking for, you won't get there unless you don't know that. SO can even be a helpful way to get started (when you're not downvoted into oblivion)

Comment: Yes, of course; no one has ever claimed that beginner questions are unsuitable on Stack Overflow, @Fabio. However, "what is an array" is likely too broad if that's *all there was*. It would need more contextualization and elaboration, like a specific programming language, an example of the type of declaration you are using, etc. And, as you said, if it were a duplicate, it should, of course, be closed as such. Still, I completely agree that SO can, should be, and *is* a resource for programmers of all experience levels, and closing questions because you already know the answer is unjustifiable

Comment: @CodyGray I mostly agree, you obviously can't answer "What arrays are" in a proper way if the OP didn't specify any language as how arrays are handled vary. But a simple answer such as "Imagine a chain of variables..." might be enough to give the idea of what an Array is to a person that learned yesterday what an if-else statement is. I think that conceptual non-language-tied question can be very helpful (for sure has been to me in the early days and it's painful seeing 99% of them closed)

Comment: "...close reasons don't actually matter..." If this would be true, why does this question here on meta even exist. I think they matter.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not providing an opinion on behaviour, merely documenting it.

Comment: @Trilarion Because people **believe** they matter, which is the correct way to go about it; but reality and belief don't always dovetail.

Comment: @FabioR. my interest is primarily in noobie questions because I search most when coding stuff I'm not deeply familiar with. Though when I am totally unfamiliar with something (["what is an array?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/839601) level) I found that traditional basic tutorials win hands down and questions like language syntax basics at SO indeed pollute my search results and make it harder for me to get to proper introductory learning resources

Comment: "as to effectively be useless at providing actionable feedback to askers" you should read the close reason OP's are shown, there's an actionable feedback: ask a new question. Before the actionable feedback was: edit the question.

Comment: @gnat yeah, the "what is an array" was just a hyperbolic example. But while looking for answers about topics i had just started learning I found tons of questions closed for example as duplicates but whose solution did not apply to both cases, or "too broad" questions that were just what i was looking for, making my research longer and more tiring. Some more regulations about question handling would make everyone's life easier and may teach newcomers how to actually write a good question

Comment: @IanKemp "...but reality and belief don't always dovetail." We have a reopen review queue which in principle should sort mistakenly closed questions out. Unfortunately it doesn't work very well. I used to recommend to edit closed questions in order to get them up and about  again. I stopped doing that.

Comment: “close reasons don't actually matter” - It matters a lot to the person who is trying ask the question.

Comment: "Then there's the fact that evermore of the bad questions that do get closed are never revisited by their one-shot-wonder askers" For that matter, sometimes when a question *is* revisited, the result should be closed for a *different* reason - and the old close vote generally sticks around.

Comment: *Of course* they matter.  "*We can't be bothered do do things right or following our own rules and guidelines*" is NOT an excuse for not doing things right.

Answer (score -9):

In my humble and personal opinion I think that that question should have not been closed at all, not for:

> seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries and more

and not as a "duplicate".

First of all he is not asking for code (or at least he didn't say that, maybe he's expecting that, but he didn't directly ask for it, we will never know).
He obviously is not asking for manuals and stuff.

For second the question specifically asks how to log crash reports of a discord bot to a file, the "duplicate" just asks how to write to file with Javascript. I have never touched a discord bot but usually, in my experience, catching a crash error is not as simple as "writing the error to a file", maybe the crash he has doesn't even produce an error to log.

There's even already an answer in the comments

> Have you thought about using something like sentry?

And that could have been all that the OP needed.

This question had surely room for improvement, but maybe giving some feedback instead of just closing the question is more beneficial to the whole community.

Lately it appears to me that people close questions just for the sake of it, just because they already know the answer, to feel paladins of justice and/or just for trolling newcomers. I think the question the OP links falls into one of this categories.

As i said in a comment somewhere around here I think that closing questions should be harder and maybe require some kind of comment instead of the prepared statements or a certain number of votes from mods, this would make closing a truly useful tool to close questions that can't and won't be answered (such as the ones VLAZ posted in the comments of this question) instead of a way to annoy someone you deem inferior.

**EDIT**(from comments):

After reading a lot of comments I came to the conclusion that this is not a solvable problem. The "purist" faction will always accuse the others of wanting easy code to copy and the others will always accuse the first of being douches.

As both kind of people coexist on the platform we are just throwing feces at each other while people who do not care about SO at all continue to post awful questions and close good questions in the background. We are too focused on fighting the other faction while bad apples do every kind of mischief in this mess.

We all just want to improve StackOverflow, but are not willing to accept other solutions but ours, when the real solution is not one OR the other, but one AND the other.

Comment: "_but maybe giving some feedback instead of just closing the question is more beneficial to the whole community_" Closing a question _is_ feedback. And more often than not, (in case the close reason doesn't fully explain it,) there are comments adding further explanation. If the OP edits their question, they have to possibility to check the "_the question should be considered for reopening_" checkbox and reviewers can reopen the question if the problems are resolved.

Comment: An example of that is *"Needs debugging details"* - it asks you to show the desired outcome and an mcve

Comment: So, you don't know if the duplicate answers the question or not? How about we trust the people who voted to close the question as such? And the OP, who can edit their question to show how the duplicate didn't answer their question and get it reopened?

Comment: Lately it appears to me that people protest closing questions just for the sake of it, just because they want a copy/paste answer, to feel paladins of justice and/or just for trolling curators.

Comment: @Ivar closing question is not proper feedback, especially when the closing reason is wrong. This question in particular just had to improve the wording and add details about what he needed to do. I agree with you that a simple comment is enough, but more often than not the question is just closed and bye bye, with no real explanation of why. I mean, if i get an "The question is too broad" i get what it means, but the why might not be immediately obvious

Comment: @HereticMonkey So you would just trust some random dude that maybe felt that two questions were the same because they shared a couple of words in the title? Don't you think that a better approach would be telling the OP that there's a similar question and then letting he decide if it applies to his case or not (obviously not if they are the exact same, but these were not)? You just assumed that the person that is closing the question knows what he is talking about, but that's not always the case.

Comment: I am totally with you on a wrong close reason being harmful because it is incorrect feedback. But I don't quite understand your objection to the question being closed as a duplicate. Do you not think that it is a duplicate?

Comment: @FabioR. not just some random person, It is 3 people who the community trusts (and hence they have the privilege to cast close votes).

Comment: @HereticMonkey if they want a copy paste answer it can be closed, but if the question contains no code this doesn't mean that he is asking for code, maybe he's just after an explanation or a concept. The rest of the comment is just a strawman, not going to address that.

Comment: You are fooling yourself if you think you can assess the motivations or thinking behind other users votes. It has been long recognized that more questions should be closed, not less. This isn't a help desk

Comment: @CodyGray well, they may share the same solution, but if i'm looking for a way to get crash reports for a discord bot I'm not landing on the other question for sure, that's all. I think that a duplicate should be a real duplicate, not be just similar

Comment: @charlietfl no, you can't know for sure what the other person was thinking, but if the question gets closed with a random reason that doesn't apply then you can probably make a guess

Comment: On Stack Overflow, "duplicate" means "you can find your answer here". In other words, this other, previously-asked question has the same answer as your question. Having a question closed as a duplicate doesn't *necessarily* imply that you should have been able to find the other question in your research. Often, askers who don't do adequate research before asking end up having their questions closed as duplicates, but that's not the only case where it can happen. Sometimes, seeing that a question has the same solution as another existing question requires some expertise in the subject-matter.

Comment: Your statement about why people close questions lately is generalized and has nothing to do with the specific question or specific reasoning. You used a very broad brush to outline what you think is a trend based on nothing but assumptions

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat the topics treated on SO are too many for mods to know everything about everything. I bet there are at least a couple of questions buried somewhere that no mod here would know anything about

Comment: *"the topics treated on SO are too many for mods to know everything about everything"* That's *absolutely* correct, and this is why moderators are not primarily involved in closing questions. There are a narrow set of subjects where I have significant expertise, but once you get into web programming, or Python, or R, I am a complete novice (or worse). This is why we leave closing to the *community*, rather than having mods do it. This allows us to get people with real subject-matter expertise handling the closing of questions, including marking of duplicates, and that's what really counts.

Comment: @CodyGray You are right, if i'm looking for a question and it's closed pointing to a different question that has the same solution i'm completely fine with that. But as always there are exceptions, and seen the load of questions that get posted on SO every day the exception becomes the norm

Comment: @CodyGray and that's the right thing to do, but not everyone applies that. Going back to what i was saying in the answer: not always (and as a common user i find these more often than not) questions are closed without good reason and even if there's still something you can do about it, finding your question closed is not really an incentive for improvement

Comment: After reading a lot of comments I came to the conclusion that this is not a solvable problem. The "purist" faction will always accuse the others of wanting easy code to copy and the others will always accuse the first of being douches. As both kind of people coexist on the platform we are just throwing feces at each other while people continue to post awful questions and close good questions in the background. We are too focused on fighting the other faction while bad apples do every kind of mischief in this mess

Comment: @charlietfl yes, it is generalized, as there are people that close random questions there are people that post awful ones. For every example I can bring for my argument, you can find one for yours. We have to address both at the same time, not just keep everything as it is not to give satisfaction to the other group. "We" need to make sacrifices to write better questions and "you" need to make sacrifices not to shoot down every question you don't like

Comment: What I want to know is how the reason is chosen when all close-voters choose different reasons

Comment: @MrMythical the [rule is here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339400/213575)

Comment: So it is possible the last voter actually picked something different, only the first voter picked seeking recommendations

Comment: @MrMythical yes, it's possible, since off topic/community specific reasons wins when there's no consensus.

Comment: @Braiam well, this explains a lot

Comment: You edited your answer with some new stuff at the bottom.  But you haven't changed the earlier parts which I strongly disagree with, claiming that it shouldn't have been closed even as a duplicate.  If you have since realized that dup closure is appropriate, you can edit your answer to say that instead, and maybe people will reverse their downvotes.  (Or not, since you don't gain or lose rep from meta answers, and having a lot of downvotes on this answer is a good signal that the community disagrees with the idea that it should be not be closed.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Well that was my opinion, and people expressed their opinion by downvoting. I find nothing wrong with this, I don't need approval from other users and other users don't need approval in my answer. Moreover my edit was some further reasoning on the matter, but is totally unrelated to the first part of the answer which I still think is true. If I wanted more rep or upvotes I could just say "We DoN't MaKe YoUr HoMeWoRk" in any random question and that would fruit me a lot, but since I care only about SO, its users, and potential ones, I answer independently from the general consensus

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming that you do still stand by the earlier parts of the answer.  I thought you might have changed your mind about that so I'd have had to reconsider my vote.  (Note that upvotes on meta don't gain you any rep.  If you just wanted rep, you'd answer bad questions on the main site even if they were exact duplicates, before other people could find and close them.  And if the answer was any good you'd usually come out ahead on rep most of the time since upvotes are worth so much more than downvotes, and most people don't downvote good answers even on bad questions.)

Comment: Yeah there are no factions. Just people who want to use Stack Overflow as they please and people who want to use Stack Overflow as intended. That's all the same faction - people.