# Inclusivity of No-Code Developers

Tags: discussion, user-experience, no-code

There are these developers nowadays that follow the no-code principle: the development is done without writing any code.

What is the current status about this way of development. Does Stack Overflow cover such Q&A? How inclusive is the site to such users?

Is asking for code appropriate as long as the person asking is a no-code developer?

---

In my understanding - which is far from a leading definition - a no-code developer is a developer not *writing* any code. I come more and more to the conclusion that this is off-topic on SO as it is about writing code:

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it.

from: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

But English is not my first language. And it can make a difference if *"people who write code because they love it"* is the specialization of *"professional and enthusiast programmers"* or an additional group.

Comment: As long as it is "programming", code is never a requirement for questions on SO. Though, for those who are not really familiar with no-code development, could you provide some related examples on SO, like existing tags or questions?

Comment: A simple example would be a developer not writing any code and also not finding any code she could use and then asking on SO for code (simplified example).

Comment: "asking for code on SO". No. Just no.

Comment: Well, I also have my own opinion about it, but wasn't the matter of the site to become more and more inclusive to all kind of developers? That's why I'm asking. The no-code development is also related to low-code development, and a low code might be one you just copy paste.

Comment: Low- and no-code isn't just using regular programming languages but you're only allowed to copy-paste what other people wrote.

Comment: But isn't the site already inclusive to all **people**? As long as one posts an on-topic question, it would well not even be a developer.

Comment: Is a no-code developer someone who doesn't write any code but asks volunteers on the internet to write their code for them?

Comment: No, @khelwood, a 'no code'  ownloads other code, fails, (or does not try),  to get it working, and then tries to download testing/debugging from SO:)

Comment: Also, 'inclusivity' reads like a lead-in to allegations of (racism, misogyny, anti-trans, [insert you favourite woke buzzword here]), should anyone disagree:(

Comment: I'm still trying to understand the distinction. Is low-/no- code something like MIT's [tag:app-inventor], or something else? Otherwise, if it's something like a bundle that can be extended with plugins using custom code, then isn't it the same as asking ["how-to" questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413152/2821954)?

Comment: If the person is a no-code developer I don't understand why they are asking for code. What good is code to someone that calls themselves a "no-code" developer; surely such a person wants *no code*. Perhaps I don't understand what a "no-code" developer is, but such a scenario sounds contradictory.

Comment: @khelwood: Good question. As SO is an internet medium that is read and write and also high on text and code works well with it, the answer probably is yes as long as it is voluntarily?

Comment: I have no idea what a "no-code developer" is. Does it mean someone who uses a visual programming language, where it is not necessary to write code? That's still on-topic, as long as it's programming. When asking questions on Meta, just like on the main site, you need to include all relevant details and context in order for others to be able to understand the question and its motivations.

Comment: @Larnu: Maybe that person wants to begin with low-code development in case no no-code answer can be given? Maybe they are not entirely limiting their world to no-code only?

Comment: Then if they are asking for code, surely they aren't asking a no-code question... The background of a person asking a question is completely irrelevant to the quality and "on topicness" of a question; so if they are asking a coding question why is the fact they are a "no-code" developer relevant?

Comment: I'm still trying to understand this "no-code developer", looks like based on [this article](https://www.techtarget.com/searchsoftwarequality/definition/no-code), "*[...]. Many others, however, allow **so-called citizen developers or non-programmers to add some custom code** to accomplish relatively simple discrete tasks, such as adding scrollbars, navigation buttons, or custom colors to webpages. Even then, these lines of code are often found in **readily available prepackaged code snippets that can be quickly added**.*" I'd assume using SO as the repo for "prepackaged code snippets"?

Comment: @Larnu: Well if a user asks for code saying she found no code so far it can make a difference if in good faith to assume she is a no-code developer could turn the question on-topic, while when no-code developers are in the wrong venue (asking for code on SO), it is clearly more often off-topic.

Comment: Why assume they are a no-code developer at all? Like I said, the fact they are (or aren't) has no relevance to the question. Should I, as a DBA, be given different treatment when I ask a question about C# because I have no idea how OOLs work? (The answer is no, I need to put just as much effort in as we expect of others, and if my understanding is fundamentally lacking, then likely [so] is the wrong place)

Comment: @Andrew T. I don't know of any leading definition. It would be more helpful to better understand your concerns if you could share your understanding what a no-code developer is for you. For me it is a developer that is not writing code on ones own but take different approaches (could be graphical, could be on the managing level, leaning to low-code etc.).

Comment: If they are using a GUI that is completely on topic, as @CodyGray mentioned, hakre. The difference there is the OP can *easily* show their efforts on what they did. If someone shows them how they can achieve the solution using code then that's fine. I, and many others, often tell users they are better off writing the code to achieve their goal instead of using the designer in tags I'm an SME, but the OP isn't a "no-code" developer, they are just trying to achieve something that is either difficult or very long winded to achieve via a designer, which is very simple in code.

Comment: @Larnu: _"Why assume they are a no-code developer at all?"_ Perhaps because they have wrote that they "found no code" so far and similar could signal that. As written, in good faith. It should be friendly to not question the asking person all the time, shouldn't it? The topic is probably too borderline for SO anyway, so there can be no clear answer.

Comment: Are you perhaps under the impression that asking for code is off-topic on Stack Overflow for "normal" developers?  That's not the case.

Comment: "found no code" doesn't mean they are a "no-code" developer, @hakre . At best it suggests that they searched the problem and found no similar solutions they could adjust for their own environment. Honestly, you're connecting to completely unrelated dots in my opinion. I, when I get stuck, frequently search for examples of similar scenarios; if I don't find a related solutiont that doesn't make me a "no-code" developer; far from it.

Comment: @RyanM: If you addressed the question to me, then no. Albeit I dislike to give code only answers, it is often that they are very well accepted.

Comment: Where does code only answers come into this?

Comment: @Larnu: The simplest answer to a question asking for code is an answer of code only.

Comment: And what do questions asking for code have to do with no-code developers?

Comment: @RyanM: That was in context to my comment addressing yours https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418534/inclusivity-of-no-code-developers?noredirect=1#comment913791_418534

Comment: That doesn't answer my question; what does code only answers have to do with the topic here, in regards to these "no-code" developers? What does code only answer have to do with @RyanM 's statement about code developers asking for code being to different to "no-code" developers?

Comment: Honestly, at this point, I would really suggest you [edit] your question to explain what a "no-code" developer is; I am honestly none the wiser after some of your comments, and possibly more confused.

Comment: In my understanding - which is far from a leading definition - a no-code developer is a developer not _writing_ any code. I come more and more to the conclusion that this is off-topic on SO as it is about writing code.

Comment: When you say "a developer not *writing* any code", do you mean that they're using a language like LabVIEW or Scratch that doesn't actual involve *writing* code, but assembling building blocks?  Or do you mean developers that copy-paste code from the internet instead of writing it themself?

Comment: A question doesn't *have* to be about code. As stated in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"* this is why questions about how to do something using the GUI in an IDE are on topic, for example. Such questions, and answers, could easily contain no code; that doesn't make the OP nor the answerer a "no-code" developer mind.

Comment: Likely both and more. I can imaging a developer that is giving inspiration or direction for others to write the code actually.

Comment: @Larnu: The question, sure. But not the user-group. And that was my question about, No-Code Developers and if the site is for them. Please see also my edit of the question.

Comment: Users aren't off topic here, @hakre , questions are.

Comment: @Larnu: The site is just not _for_ those users. See the on-topic reference. Thats what I meant. Perhaps you as well, if not please clarify.

Comment: Who the user is has **nothing** to do with whether their question is on topic or not; @hakre . I, as a DBA, doesn't mean I can go to [DBA.se] and ask the best way to cook egg fried rice... The same applies here; a cook can come to [so] and ask about programming.

Comment: @Larnu: Sure, the site has to be _for_ the user **and** the users' questions has to be _on topic_. And your example is misleading, this is covered by the sentence I quoted: The chef might not be a professional programmer (cooking is theirs profession) but an enthusiast. Not really in the details with the DBA on-topic description but why would you as DBA want to ask about how to partition your pan with eggs on that site when it is most likely not made for that?

Comment: It's an example of why your thinking that users are off topic is wrong, @hakre . It's an intentionally wrong statement as your understanding is wrong. I gave the other side of your flawed understanding; that I'd types of users are off topic then other types of users must be *on topic* (and thus can ask whatever they want). Again users aren't off-topic, questions are.

Comment: [No-code platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-code_development_platform). A [list of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-code_development_platform#Notable_no-code_development_platforms). Somewhat related is [GitHub Copilot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub_Copilot) (based on [GPT-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPT-3)).

Comment: Can you add some example questions? There must be a lot of them by now.

Comment: @Larnu: Don't beat a dead horse. While I once (shortened) wrote users are off-topic it was meant that only users questions can be off-topic, and again to clarify, the site can be for a user but _must_ not, and while the site has its own topic, only a users Q&A works can be compared against that ("on-topic") and not the user per-se or the userprofile etc..

Comment: Another list is in *[Getting To Know No-Code and Low-Code, And How To Get Started](https://www.sololearn.com/blog/207)*.

Comment: For instance, [Podio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Podio) ([537 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/podio)) and GitHub Copilot ([36 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-copilot)) have their own tags on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Why must there be a lot of Questions by now? It was something I was interested in to discuss and get some inspiration. I normally ignore asking for code questions personally but wanted to connect a bit more with meta about it.

Comment: @hakre: Because it has been part of the [hype cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hype_cycle#Five_phases) for several years. And the fear cycle - *"Oh no, are we all going to lose our jobs due to low-code platforms!?"*. For instance, it [was mentioned](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j831V8dzncE&t=53m18s) in Uncle Stef's stream in January 2021 (at 53 min 18 secs).

Comment: Which can also lead to the opposite that "I found no code" must not mean the person is a no-code enthusiast. And I have not seen (which is only subjective) no-code questions I would have clearly identified as such (again from my subjective opinion). So yeah, I could have expected such users, but it seems its not so much the site for indeed.

Comment: And [in August 2020](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FF24fh48-Og&t=31m15s) (at 31 min 15 secs) and [in December 2020](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-UGV7w_qa4&t=14m45s) (at 14 min 45 secs).

Comment: "[No-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-code_development_platform)" and "[low-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-code_development_platform)" (platforms) are well established terms and should not be conflated with anything else (it causes too much confusion). For instance, a no-code developer should only mean someone who uses one of the (notable) no-code platforms.

Comment: Maybe. These two terms terms I only know from marketing not from the profession. And programming without code is pretty old like with pen and paper drawing a flow-chart can be or the tools to learn programming that use visuals.

Answer (score 10):

> Is asking for code appropriate as long as the person asking is a no-code developer?

Wrong question.

1. Asking for code is allowed. As long as it formulated to be on-topic. Questions that ask "How to do <something>" are among the most popular on Stack Overflow. 
   *Who* asked the question is irrelevant. An on-topic question is on-topic regardless of the author.
2. If a no-code programmer asked a question about code, there is a chance it is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). No-code platforms and approaches do not lean on code (as the name implies). 
   Asking for how to solve a given problem X is probably a better approach. Asking for code might be the Y.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we have an inclusivity problem. SO, and its volunteers don't discriminate at all based on the background of the person asking a question.

Good questions get answered, bad questions get closed. The person asking the question is not relevant, only the content being posted is evaluated.

One could even be a welder, or a rocket pilot, as long as their question follows the SO standards, it will be well received.

Comment: *"bad questions get closed"* I know what you meant, but I'm not going to let that stop me from nitpicking the wording. Bad questions can be downvoted or simply ignored, but they aren't necessarily closed. Only questions that fail to meet [our specific requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) are closed.

Comment: @CodyGray: Thanks for the reference again, no-code is off-topic then: _"people who write code because they love it."_ In my understanding a no-code developer is not _writing_ code.

Comment: I still have no idea what you're trying to say, @hakre. "Code" is generally used as a synecdoche for "programming" and/or "software development". The site's scope is not intended to be limited to people who are literally writing code. Visual programming languages are also on-topic, as is architecture, algorithms, etc.

Comment: I beg your pardon, but I need a more easy language. The on-topic description scopes the user-group both as programmers (which likely matches what you say?) and then specializes to "who love writing code". So if a visual developer is asking for written code because she loves writing code = site is for her. If a no-code developer is asking for written code and they dislike writing code = site is not for them. At least this is my current understanding.

Comment: First off, there's no "who love writing code" in [the definition of what is on-topic for the site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Marketing-speak on the homepage doesn't define our scope. Second, that's not a "specialization"; at best, it's an intensifier or metonym, but it's really just a throwaway phrase someone thought sounded cool. It implies nothing. As you've been told *repeatedly*, but for some reason ignore, the site doesn't care about people. They're not relevant to the scope. I simply cannot believe that you genuinely are this confused about the site's scope. @hakre

Comment: Oh, hopefully the site cares about people, it surprises me a bit to read from a mod it would not, to say the least. And just for clarity, verbatim it is: "people who write code because they love it.".

Comment: This site cares not at all about people. Not even a tiny little bit. By design and since the beginning, the site has only ever cared about content. And that quoted phrase *still* doesn't appear in the Help Center pages that define the site's scope. @hakre

Comment: Maybe you get a different page here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , or you use different names for it or whatever. That is the one I quoted from. Be it homepage, help-center, marketing or whatever - only related to the reference you kindly shared.- And I can't imagine a moderator can speak for the company or override its legal obligations. Nor that these sentences were just written down without thinking about other topics than marketing. Lets leave it as-is.

Comment: Oh, sorry; I finally see what the confusion is. Yeah, that phrase doesn't belong there, and the wording is sub-optimal. I will fix it.

Comment: And then you will tell me, you're totally not in a conflict of interest. The force for moderators must be really thin... .

Comment: I don't understand what that means. I was trying to explain to you the site's rules and how they are meant to be interpreted. You found a place where the official guidance was misleadingly worded and causing you to think something else. I had missed that nuance, because I'd read the page so many times and already knew what it was trying to say. After realizing what the issue you'd noted was (sorry it took me so long), I fixed it. Isn't that the whole point of posting on Meta?